# Which punctuations to use when bringing up questions in this way?

Tags: punctuation, writing-style, questions, writing

In **formal** writing, is the following usage of punctuations acceptable?

> I keep asking myself. Who am I? Where am I from? And where am I going?

I'm not quite sure whether using a period after `I keep asking myself` is weird. To me, the natural choice would have been a colon, but this also would have made the first interrogative sentence have to start with a lower case `w` whereas subsequent ones, as they follow a question mark, must begin with a capitalised `W` , like `..asking myself: who am I? Where am I from...`, which doesn't make much sense to me either.

Of course, alternatively, I can reorganise these interrogative sentences into clauses like

> I keep asking myself: who I am, where I am from and where I am going.

But this feels *much* less emotionally charged than the first one, which makes it not so desirable to me.

Comment: It is not unacceptable (according to some style guides, so how can the others mandate otherwise?) to use a capital after a colon.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thanks. Could you provide a reference for this? For what I know though, a colon means the sentence still continues, but using a capital letter indicates "here goes another sentence".

Answer (score -1):

A semicolon is usually use to indicate a list or enumeration. But either one will be understood as the questions belonging to the statement.

I keep asking myself; who I am, where I am from and where I am going.

Comment: No, a semicolon is [wrong before a list](http://www.gcsu.edu/writingcenter/punctuation-rules).